# How I am testing that someone is connected to my server?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an Android Client and I want to be sure that can connect to a Java Server.

My server is this

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int portNumber = 5885;
    System.out.println("Starting..");

    // We use a try-with-resources statement to ensure that all sockets and 
    // readers/writers are closed when the program terminates
    try (
            // Set up the server socket on a specified port number
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

            // Wait until a connection is made by a client and accept its socket
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            // Set up a writer to the client socket
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            // Set up a reader from the client socket
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            // Missing Part

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port " + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and the Client is trying to connect with this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.board_layout);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

 }

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

How I can check if someone is connected to server?? With an

```
if (clientSocket != null)
     System.out.println("Someone is in");
```

or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if a client has connected, `serverSocket.accept()` will block until someone connects. This should also be in a loop that spawns a dedicated thread for each client.

If you want to reliably confirm a client is connected, I would use heartbeats (A message from the client that's entire purpose is to confirm the status of the connection):

Make each client send heartbeats to the server. e.g have a thread on the client side that sleeps for a duration (10 seconds) and then wakes up to send a heartbeat. This way if you do not receive a heartbeat for a period of time you know that there is a connection issue.

Just to illustrate the concept:

Server:

```
public void startServer() throws IOException{
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9209);
        List<ClientThread> clientThreads = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
        boolean running = true;
        while(running){
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(clientSocket);
                clientThread.run();
                clientThreads.add(clientThread);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        for(ClientThread thread : clientThreads){
            thread.shutdown();
        }
}





 public class ClientThread extends Thread{
        private BufferedReader in;
        private volatile boolean running = true;
        private long lastHeartBeat;

        public ClientThread(Socket socket) throws IOException{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }

        public void shutdown(){
            running = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running){
                try {
                    if(in.readLine().equalsIgnoreCase("HeartBeat")){
                        lastHeartBeat = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }else{
                        //do something else 
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Each client creates one of the following:

```
public class HeartBeatThread extends Thread{

    PrintWriter out;
    volatile boolean running = true;

    public HeartBeatThread(Socket socket) throws IOException{
        this.out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            try {
                sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            out.println("HeartBeat");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 100% explained.

Answer (score 1):

## If you want to be notified when a client connects..

Just put a print statement after `Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();`. The method `ServerSocket#accept` will block execution until a client has been accepted, which means a print statement after `accept` will only trigger if a client has been accepted.

```
try(ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5885)) {
    while(true) {
        try {
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted!");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // error accepting client
        }
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // error starting server
}
```

## If you want to check if a user is online..

You need to assign a unique ID to each user. You would then need a data structure to store every user - one that allows you to grab the user based on an ID may be preferred (`Map` would work).

## When you accept a connection..

Generate a `UUID`, then store the `Socket` in a data structure that allows you to access values using a key (in this case, the `UUID`.

```
class Server {
    private static final Map<UUID, Socket> CONNECTIONS = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5885)) {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Socket socket = server.accept();
                    UUID uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID();

                    CONNECTIONS.put(uniqueId, Socket);
                } catch(IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); // error accepting client
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // error starting server
        }
    }

    public static boolean userExists(UUID uniqueId) {
        return CONNECTIONS.containsKey(uniqueId);
    }
}
```

You could also do this with usernames. Or better yet, create your own type that consists of a `Socket`, a `UUID` and a `String username;`:

```
class User {
    private Socket socket;
    private UUID uniqueId;
    private String username;

    // constructor, getters, behaviors
}
```

And maintain a `List` of `User` rather than a `Map<UUID, Socket>`:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
```

When you need to check the list, convert it to a `List` of the property you want to check:

```
String nameOfUser = ...;

boolean containsUser= users.stream().map(User::getUsername).anyMatch(name -> name.equals(nameOfUser));
```

This assumes `User` has a `getUsername()` method. Same could be done for `UUID`.